# Linq To Sql - Making a dynamic search for the Application layer without exposing DAL layer as DLL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, data-access-layer, business-logic-layer, application-layer

**Linq to SQL, C#.**

I have 3 layers: DAL,BL,Application.
I want to build functions of search in the BL for each table so those functions get as a parameter 'where' expresstion from the Application layer. The advantage in this approach is one function for each table so the client can search in a free and dynamic way insted of givving him 5 (for example) ways; restrict his search.

For that I need to give my Application layer a DLL of my DAL layer. Doing that is not a good approach to solve the problem (givving the user to build his search dynamicly insted of restrict him with a builded up search functions).
If the Application layer have a DLL to my DAL layer, the Aplication layer can declare a ContextObject and do bad things for my Data-Base.

What can I do for solving this problem?

Thanks alot, 
Stav Alfi.

**Update 1:**

As you know, the Linq to Sql build a class to each table. 
I dont want to expose the DAL DLL to the Application layer so I can not use Linq to Sql's classes in the Application layer. The solution I found is to build classes that look the same to the Linq to Sql's classes, so the Application layer can use them.
The BL layer is resposnibol for convring those classes.
From the fact that the Application layer does not use Linq to Sql's classes, I can't give to the Application layer a IQueryable (Any result of Any function of the BL layer is converted to the Application layer's classes).

**Update 2:**

The Linq to Sql have LinqClientDB.designer.cs and it Build up those classes

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.DatabaseAttribute(Name="ClientDB")]
public partial class LinqClientDBDataContext : System.Data.Linq.DataContext

[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.Clients")]
public partial class Client : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

If I expose the DAL layer to the Application layer, the Application layer can have access to the LinqClientDBDataContext class. this is not a good approach.
So in the BL layer I convert the DAL.Client class to a BL.Client class but then I cant have a dynamic search on the Client's table. What can I do?

Comment: Just to make sure - is this LINQ-to-SQL or the Entity Framework?

Comment: I think, if you have palaced your Entities in DAL so there won't be a way, and placing Entities in DAL is not a recamanded pattern, if not, @p.s.w.g's answer will work

Comment: Im using Linq to SQL, and the Linq to sql build up a suitable class to each table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exposing `IQueryable<T>` through your BL does not expose your DAL. Since you want to encapsulate the database entities in separate classes for the application layer, you can still do this, although the application will be more limited in the types of queries it can run.

```
// DAL
public class Entity { ... }

// BL
public class EntityInfo : Entity { ... }

...

public IQueryable<EntityInfo> GetEntities()
{
    return from e in dbContext.Entities
           select new EntityInfo
           {
               // populate your application layer object
           }
}
```

Here's an alternative way of coding it that provides the same result

```
public Expression<Func<Entity, EntityInfo>> materializeEntityInfo =
    e => new EntityInfo { .. };

public IQueryable<EntityInfo> GetEntities()
{
    return dbContext.Entities.Select(materializeEntityInfo);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but in your answer you must expose the DAL layer, else you can not use the Linq 2 sql claases (Linq 2 sql build a class to each table). Please read my update. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Incase the Application layer run this code: GetEntities().Where((EntityInfo1)=> EntityInfo1.Age>40). It will firstly get all the table to the ram after all the objects were converted and only then search whitch entities are over the age of 40. Is this the best sulotion I can find? What if my table consist of milions entities?

Comment: @StavAlfi This would work like any other database query. It won't execute any code on the server until you create an `IEnumerator<T>`. `OrderBy`, `Where`, `Take`, `Skip`, and most other extension methods would all work as if you ran it against the database itself.

Comment: When this query will be excuted, for the filtring function do its work it must firstly convert all the entities to entityInfo-save on the ram all the entityInfo. Am I correct?

Comment: @StavAlfi No. If you returned `IEnumerable<T>` you'd be somewhat correct, but `IQueryable<T>` will defer execution until it has to return an `EntityInfo`, and at that point, it will convert any expressions it's been given into a sql query. The only time this won't work is if you provide an expression that LINQ-to-SQL cannot convert to a sql query.

Comment: Only for my understanding, From your example, Does the part of converting the entity to entityInfo is made in the sql and not in C# code?

Comment: @StavAlfi If you use this method, technically no `Entity` will ever be created. The Linq-to-SQL `IQueryProvider` will inspect the query expression and produce an `EntityInfo` directly (or whatever the final query expression selected).

Comment: Im sory but your solution does not give me the option to filter, I get this exception -Method 'BusinessLogic.Client Convert(ClientDataAccessLayer.Client)' has no supported translation to SQL.-  when I try any filtering like : ClientsLogic.Clients().Where((Client1) => Client1.Size == 12345).

Comment: @StavAlfi You cannot call arbitrary functions in linq-to-sql, so your `Convert` method cannot be used that way (see the second part of my answer where I show the use of expressions). Either post the source code of `Convert` or possibly open up a new question on that topic.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but im out of ideas. And the convert is a action that gets DAL.Client object and convert it to BL.Client - new BL.Client(DALClient.ID,DALClient.Name,..); Do I need to redesign my project? If I must, how would you do it?

Comment: @StavAlfi You cannot call a arbitraty functions, including constructors with Linq-to-Sql. use an `Expression<Func<T, U>>` (not a simple `Func<T, U>` or a method) with the initializer syntax I showed in my answer. something like `x => new BL.Client { ID = x.ID, ... }`

Comment: I still get the same exception.

Comment: @StavAlfi without seeing more of the code, I won't be able to help you. Either post the more code in the question or open up a new question on that topic.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15723202/how-the-application-layer-will-be-able-to-dynamicly-query-the-db-in-the-dal-laye

Answer (score 0):

You can make the context class `internal` while the entity classes are `public`.

[image]

This would allow you to create service classes in your DAL that return entity classes (as `IEnumerable`s) from a context that is not exposed to the client.

Although this is true, it is often advisable (as p.s.w.g said) to have DTO or view model objects exposed to the client (or application layer) because is abstracts the DAL.